# Windows-Installer: How to unpack application into TempFolder, run it and delete it?

Tags: windows-installer, temporary-files

I have own installation procedure InstallInit.exe. I need to include it into  MSI installer, so the windows-installer will:

1. Unpack my InstallInit.exe into Temp Folder
2. Launch [Temp Folder]\InstallInit.exe /withargumets
3. Delete [Temp Folder]\InstallInit.exe

Do you have any tips how to do it? I know only how to do the step 2 (through Custom Actions).

Note1: I am using VS2010 to create the installer.

Note2: I am OK also with another folder (i.e. target dir in Program Files). This would solve #1. I just need to delete the InstallInit.exe after installation finished.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Put the InstallInit.exe into Binary-Table
(2) Create a CustomAction for unpack
(3) Create a CustomAction for Launch
(4) Change  RemoveFile-Table - add  InstallInit.exe (InstallMode = 1)

Comment: Could you be more specific, please? I have no Idea how to do your steps 1,2 and 4. Is it possible to these steps in VS2010?

Comment: why dont you use wix? Not sure if the steps mentioned above are available with VS.

Comment: We already use NSIS-based installers, the 3 steps are easy to implement in it. But customer required MSI installer because he wants to manage installations in his network via "group policy". (To be truth I have very slight knowledge about the "group policy installations", so I don't know if it really works only with MSI installer)

Answer (score 0):

As part of your solution, create a program which performs steps 1-3 and call THAT program as a Custom Action

Comment: I am afraid this is impossible. How could InstallInit.exe do step #1: unpack itself from where? And how could InstallInit.exe do the step #3:to delete itself if it is running?

Comment: As part of your solution, you create a project, say PREINSTALL.EXE, which performs steps 1-3. You add PREINSTALL.EXE as a custom action